# How to keep iterating rows in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.5

I've been working on this program for a while and am not sure on how to keep generating a question. Basically I have csv with two columns questions and answers. I'm trying to create a program that reads the csv and selects a random row. This row has the question and corresponding answer. It should ask the user a question and wait for a response. After the response it should ask another question until the user types something that will break it. This is where I'm having trouble, as I'm only getting it to ask one question before it ends.

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import random

text = {r[0]: r[1] for r in csv.reader(open('QandA.csv'))}
question = random.choice(list(text.keys()))

correctAnswers = 1
questionsAsked = 1

successful = False
isBreak = False

while not successful or isBreak:
    user_input = input(f"{question} ").format(question)

    if user_input == text[question]:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm fully understanding what the program is trying to accomplish. If you want them to answer questions until they type a specific keyword to break out, like "quit", this should work.

```
import csv
import random

text = {r[0]: r[1] for r in csv.reader(open('QandA.csv'))}
questions = list(text.keys())
question = random.choice(questions)

correctAnswers = 0
questionsAsked = 0

while True:
    questionsAsked += 1
    user_input = input(f"{question} ").format(question)

    if user_input.strip().lower() == "quit": break
    elif user_input == text[question]: correctAnswers += 1
    else: pass #do something here for incorrect answer

    question = random.choice(questions) #get new question
```

Hope that helps. Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was looking for. My bad on the question wording, wasn't quite sure how to word it.